# Socket.IO Library for Xamarin.Forms(Portable Class Library)

Tags: node.js, sockets, xamarin, socket.io, xamarin.forms

which library should I use to connect **Socket.IO** from C# **Xamarin Form(Portable Class Library)** to **NodeJS** app. I want to create cross platform app for mobile and communicate with the help of sockets with web app.
My all of the nodejs code is written with socket.io library.

This is the sample code, since I cannot not paste my all of the socket code, it is too big to paste so I am pasting a sample code.

**NodeJS Code:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        console.log('a user connected');
        socket.on('hi', function(data) {
            console.log('Hello WOrld');
        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('user disconnected');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some socket.io client implementation for xamarin as well :

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/socketioclientdotnet

You can use this xamarin component with your client applications to use sockets provided by your node server.

You can try these two as well :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/rda.SocketsForPCL/

**DEPRACATED ::** https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket.Portable.Core/

instead use https://github.com/NVentimiglia/WebSockets.Pcl

Comment: This implementation (https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/socketioclientdotnet) is for Android native app, I need implementation for cross platform app.

2: this implementation(https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl) uses byte data to be sent on the server, and right now I cannot change my server code. My all server code receives data on specific events in string.

Comment: I think the last link Websocket protable core provides sending data via string , i just saw their git https://github.com/NVentimiglia/WebSocket.Portable

Comment: ass you can see the link https://github.com/websockets/ws I would have to change my server code if I have to use websockets. this is the problem, i dont want to change my server code written with socket.io, I want socket.io similar library for xamarin.forms

Answer (score 1):

You can build a [Xamarin.Forms Apps with .NET Standard](https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/) and then use [SocketIoClientDotNet version1.0.2-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SocketIoClientDotNet/1.0.2-beta1).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried [SocketIOClient Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SocketIOClient/) by [DogHappy](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/DogHappy). It's latest stable version 1.0.2.6 as of today (18th December 2019,) works perfectly with the Xamarin.Forms version 4.2.0.709249 on both Android and iOS. Library is pretty much hassle free and stable on both platforms. It's [Github repository](https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp) explains how to consume this package very well.